# How to add information to the method fill helper in XCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, methods

I don't know how to explain it very well, so that's why an image value is more than one thousand words, I hope my screenshot help.

Thank you.

[image]

EDIT:
As you can see in the first `id init`, I'm pointing to a rectangle that has some information about `id init` constructor/method/selector, but this information comes from apple `NSObject init` I guess, and I want my constructor/method/selector prompts extra information while selecting in the method fill helper, as you can see in the second `id initWithGPSPointNum ...` there is no information, because I don't know how to put there the information I want.

Comment: This question needs more information other than a screenshot.

Comment: It is actually quite self explanatory by the screenshots.  You can see in the first for the default implementation of `init` there is some documentation text provided describing the method.  How does he get that text to be detected by autocomplete for his own methods?

Comment: I edited explaining what I want (same as the screenshot) PD: don't down vote because you want to do, please, it's a valid question...

Comment: I think this article might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560292/xcode-comments-autocompletion-appledoc-style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The help hints come from the installed docsets.

You can generate and install docsets for your own custom classes and install them in Xcode to get this extra information as well as auto-completion.

One way that is convenient is [appledoc](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/)

This uses a convenient and familiar syntax, and produces web formatted output as well as docsets and can even be configured to generate and install the docsets automatically.